# What is there to do in Orlando, Florida?

Tags: usa, florida, orlando

Aside from the Disney World, what else is there to explore in and around Orlando? I'll be staying at a Disney World hotel with my family for a week.

Comment: NBA, Orlando Magic?

Comment: The question seems a bit broad, perhaps you could add interests and dislikes you have (ie it's relevant if you don't like going to the ocean)

Comment: I think this question is far too broad for this site.  Check out this page about [how to ask questions](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask-beta) and especially the blog posts for the types of questions this SE site is for.

Comment: The community needs to figure out if this type of question is appropriate for this site.

Comment: Thank you for your participation, but such a vague question is only receiving even weaker answers. What problem are you trying to solve? What *specifically* are you looking for? Without a specific question, users can only guess about what advice would actually help you. The result is random, unqualified chit-chat. See **http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6/are-recommendation-questions-on-topic/26#26**

Answer (score 1):

Lots. You can see all the attractions at http://visitorlando.com

Answer (score 0):

There's a Wakepark if you want to go wakeboarding: http://www.orlandowatersports.com/.